# Connecting database (MongoDB) and backend (nodejs) running in docker containers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

First, I looked through several discussion with similar problems and it still did not work.

I have a mongodb docker container running, I did port forwarding with -p command
to be exact this is the command I ran:

```
sudo docker run -t -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongo mongo-0000
```

docker ps shows container running

```
9d9040a7bd66   mongo-0000   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo
```

as in another thread it was suggested to change mongodb bindip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 , which I also did (I tried both ways).

then I am trying to start up a backend app container with nodejs express backend app, I have had them working fine together on a VM, not on docker jet.

And i get following error

```
    sudo docker run conduit-backend
Listening on port 3000

/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:261
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:260:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:162:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NativeConnection instance at:
    at /ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:288:17
    at NativeConnection.Connection.error (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:489:12)
    at /ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:520:15
    at /ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:69:21
    at /ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:229:14
    at Server.<anonymous> (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:259:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:485:26)
    at Server.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/ConduitReactApp/src/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:21)
    at Pool.emit (node:events:378:20)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at Socket.emit (node:events:378:20)
```

Also, inside app.js (in the backend app) for connecting to mongoDB it reads so

```
if(isProduction){
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/conduit');
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
}
```

What is still wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should run your mongodb image after that you should mount mongo container to app container while run your app container. For example,

```
docker run -p xxxx:xxxx --link mongo:mongo <image-name>
```

And to connect mongodb like this, you should use a connection string like below,

```
'mongodb://mongo:27017/<db-name>'
```